# Local Homeomorphism that is not a Covering Space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

> Let $f:(0,10)\rightarrow S^{1}$ be a function defined by $f(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$. Obviously, $f$ is a local homeomorphism but $((0,10), f)$ *is not* a Covering Space for $S^{1}$

I found this example on the Massey.
I think that, if I take an open neighborhood $\mathcal{U}$ of $(1,0)$, then $f^{-1}(\mathcal{U}) = (0,\varepsilon)\sqcup (2\pi -\varepsilon , 2\pi +\varepsilon)$ but
$$f\mid_{(0,\varepsilon)}:(0,10)\rightarrow\mathcal{U}$$
is not an homeomorphism because $f$ is not surjective. So $\mathcal{U}$ is not evenly covered by $f$ and $((0,10), f)$ is not a Covering Space for $S^{1}$. Is it right?

Comment: You are actually assuming that $\cal U$ is an open interval (and not a more general open neighbourhood). Also the domain of $f|_{(0, \epsilon)}$ is $(0, \epsilon)$. Apart from those minor points you are right.

Comment: Note that all fibres of a locally trivial map are homeomorphic. Compare the fibres of $f$ over $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$.

Comment: @Rob Arthan yes (0,\varepsilon), typo error.

Comment: @Tyrone, {0,2π} and {π,3π}. So?

Comment: $0$ is not in any fiber.

Comment: What Paul says (i.e. compare $\{2\pi\}$ and $\{\pi,3\pi\}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but you argument is not sufficiently precise. In fact let us check whether $(1,0)$ has an evenly covered open neigborhood $U$. You **cannot** assume that $f^{-1}(U) = (0,\varepsilon) \cup (2\pi -\varepsilon , 2\pi +\varepsilon)$ because you do not know anything about $U$. However, you know that $2\pi \in f^{-1}(U)$, thus there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(2\pi -\varepsilon, 2\pi+\varepsilon) \subset f^{-1}(U)$. We may of course assume $\varepsilon < \pi$. But $V = f((2\pi -\varepsilon, 2\pi+\varepsilon))$ is an open neighborhood of $(1,0)$, distinct from $S^1$, which is contained in $U$, hence also $V$ is evenly covered. Now you get
$$f^{-1}(V) = (0, \varepsilon) \cup (2\pi -\varepsilon, 2\pi+\varepsilon) .$$
Sheets over $V$ must be mapped by $f$ homeomorphically onto $V$, thus must have the form $(2\pi k -\varepsilon, 2\pi k+\varepsilon)$. Thus $f^{-1}(V)$ does not have a decomposition into sheets.

Note, however, that Tyrone's comment gives a shorter approach. The fibers $f^{-1}((1,0)) = \{2\pi\}$ and $f^{-1}((-1,0)) = \{\pi, 3\pi \}$ do not have the same number of elements.