# If $p : Y \to X$ is a covering map with a connected $Y$, can the restriction $p \mid_Z : Z \to X$ be a covering map for $Z \subsetneqq Y$?

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

In [Local Homeomorphism that is not a Covering Space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3864203) it was asked whether $f : (0,10) \to S^1, f(t) = e^{it}$, is a covering map. It is easy to see that it is not.

The map $f$ is the restriction of the covering map $F : \mathbb R \to S^1, F(t) = e^{it}$. Thus a more general question is this:

> If $p : Y \to X$ is a covering map, is it possible that $p \mid_Z : Z \to X$ is a covering map for some proper subspace $Z \subsetneqq Y$?

The trivial answer is yes. $Y$ can be the disjoint union of open subsets $Y_1,Y_2$ such that both $p \mid_{Y_i}$ are covering maps.

**But what if $Y$ is connected?** If the answer is "no" in that case, then we have an alternative proof showing that the above $f$ cannot be a covering map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We give a negative answer for connected and *locally connected* $Y$. Note that $Y$ is locally connected iff $X$ is. The general case remains open.

The case $X = \emptyset$ is trivial, so let us consider $X \ne \emptyset$.

Let $Z \subset Y$ be a subspace such that $q = p \mid_Z : Z \to X$ is a covering map. Thus in particular $Z \ne \emptyset$. We show that $Z$ is open and closed in $Y$ which implies $Z = Y$.

1. $Z$ is open in $Y$:

Let $z \in Z$. There exists an open neigborhood $V$ of $z$ in $Z$ which is mapped by $q$  homeomorphically onto an open subset $U \subset X$. We now invoke the answer to [If a covering map $p : Y \to X$ maps $V \subset Y$ homeomorphically onto an open $U \subset X$, must $V$ be open in $Y$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3865287) to see that $V$ is open in $Y$. Note that $p$ maps $V \subset Y$ homeomorphically onto $U$.

Let us emphasize that in the above proof we only used that $q$ is a *local homeomorphism* which is weaker than being a covering map. We also did not use that $Y$ is connected.

2. $Y \setminus Z$ is open in $Y$:

Let $y \in Y \setminus Z$. There exists a connected open neighborhood $U$ of $x = p(y)$ in $X$ which is evenly covered both by $p$ and by $q$. Hence there exists a family $\{V_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ of pairwise disjoint open subsets of $Y$ such that $p^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} V_\alpha$ and such that the restrictions $p_\alpha : V_\alpha \to U$ of $p$ are homeomorphisms. There exists a unique $\alpha(y) \in A$ such that $y \in V_{\alpha(y)}$. We claim that $V_{\alpha(y)} \cap Z = \emptyset$ which proves 2. Assume that there is an element $z  \in V_{\alpha(y)} \cap Z$. Since $q(z) = p(z) \in U$ and $U$ is evenly covered by $q$, we find an open $W \subset q^{-1}(U)$ which is mapped by $q$ homeomorphically onto $U$ and contains $z$. Hence $W$ is connected. It is covered by the pairwise disjoint open $W_\alpha = W \cap V_\alpha$, thus only one $W_\alpha$ can be nonempty.  This means $W = W_\alpha$, i.e. $W \subset V_\alpha$. Hence $W = V_\alpha$ because both sets are mapped by $p$ homeomorphically onto $U$. But we have $z \in W$, thus $z \in  V_\alpha$ and therefore $\alpha = \alpha(y)$. This is a contradiction because $y \notin W$ and $y \in V_{\alpha(y)}$.